# Calculate person years by subtracting start date from end date

Tags: r, date, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    id start_date death_date
    1 2011-05-20 2014-12-11
    2 2014-08-01 2016-01-05
    3 2005-01-02 2015-10-20
    4 2015-06-30 2016-02-14
    5 2014-07-01 2014-09-03
```

I want to create a new column that contains the difference between death_date and start_date in months UNLESS start_date is before 2014-05-31. If start_date < 2014-05-31, then I want the new column to be the difference between death_date and 2014-05-31 in months.

Code to create sample dataframe:

```
id <- c(1:5)
start_date <- c(as.Date("2011-05-20"), as.Date("2014-08-01"),
            as.Date("2005-01-02"), as.Date("2015-06-30"),
            as.Date("2014-07-01"))

death_date <- c(as.Date("2014-12-11"), as.Date("2016-01-05"),
            as.Date("2015-10-20"), as.Date("2016-02-14"),
            as.Date("2014-09-03"))

example_dates <- data.frame(id, start_date, death_date)
```

Comment: `example$difference <- example$death_date - example$start_date`?

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus but with the stipulation that if start_date is before 2014-05-31, to do example_dates$death_date - "2014-05-31". This is my question

Comment: replace `example$start_date` in the above comment with `ifelse(example$start_date < as.Date('2014-05-31'), as.Date('2014-05-31'), example$start_date)`

Comment: It's generally a good idea to also provide desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df$new_col <- round(ifelse(df$start_date<as.Date("2014-05-31"), 
               df$death_date-as.Date("2014-05-31"), df$death_date-df$start_date)/30, 2)

  # id start_date death_date new_col
# 1  1 2011-05-20 2014-12-11    6.47
# 2  2 2014-08-01 2016-01-05   17.40
# 3  3 2005-01-02 2015-10-20   16.90
# 4  4 2015-06-30 2016-02-14    7.63
# 5  5 2014-07-01 2014-09-03    2.13
```